# Javascript button click get input from div

Tags: javascript

I have a question about something that I can not explain, so I give an example what my output needs to be.

This is my script,

```js
function myfunction(e) {
  var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input id="value" type="text" name="" value="banana">
  <button id="button" type="button" name="button" onclick="myfunction()">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <input id="value" type="text" name="" value="apple">
  <button id="button" type="button" name="button" onclick="myfunction()">Button</button>
</div>
```

As you can see only the input value is different. If I run the script now and I click the div where apple is my value is banana. But i need to have it if I click on div banana it alert "banana" if I click apple it alert "apple". How can I do this It need to go trought 1 button click not on a div click. It is really hard to explane so if you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: First of all `id` should be unique

Comment: @SagarJajoriya no sorry that can't be beacause it is auto genarate.

Comment: Then you're doomed! `id` not should, but __must__ be unique, otherwise you'll have to use nonobvious code hacks and other stuff.

Comment: getbyid() get the first occurence of the ID it's why you always have the same. Moreover ID must be unique otherwise it cause big problems in your DOM

Comment: If auto generated then append random number at end and pass that to your function for myfunction()

Answer (score 3):

First of all **never** use an id twice.
The code below alerts the value from the input, that is a sibling element of the button, from which the function is called.

```js
function myfunction(e) {
  var input = e.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]; //or whatever selector you need
  var value = input.value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input type="text" name="" value="banana">
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="myfunction(this)">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <input type="text" name="" value="apple">
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="myfunction(this)">Button</button>
</div>
```